# What does "feeding the leak" mean?

Tags: meaning

In *Avatar* (2009), Miles ordering her pilots to attack Trudy:

> Miles: Keep her in your sights.

The pilot who is flying Miles flight responds:

> Pilot: Purging. **Feeding the leak**.

What does "feeding the leak" mean ?

Comment: Probably invented 'spacecraft jargon' made up by the scriptwriters.

Comment: I just searched the script and can't find that dialogue at all. I thought maybe you misheard some of it, but either you misheard all of it or it is just some unscripted babble added in foley, in which case I would not try to analyse it.

Comment: @Astralbee This movie has two editions: Theatrical and Extended. Online scripts do not match the Extended edition, which is the version my question is related to.

Comment: I've found the script on line, and a couple of memes, and it's as quoted by the OP - but I've no idea what it means!

Comment: It's not a common English idiom. I suggest you ask on Movies and TV, or SF and Fantasy Stack Exchange. (Probably it relates to a system being purged/emptied, but without a knowledge of the operating procedures of Avatar's spaceships I don't see how we can know what is happening.)

Comment: What @StuartF said. If you're asking because you're learning English, then you can ignore this. If you want to understand because you're a fan of Avatar, then ask in [movies.se] or [scifi.se].

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A bit of Googling reveals that "feed the leak" is a strategy used to deal with decompression issues in space.

It is discussed in [this stack exchange question and answer](https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/40626/first-actions-taken-after-identifying-a-potentially-catastrophic-decompression) and on [this NASA site](https://ntrs.nasa.gov/citations/20140012987).

I don't claim to fully understand it but from what I can grasp it means to continue to allow stored gas to be pumped through the system to the leak rather than isolate it. Why this is deliberately done, I don't know - presumably it either gives some kind of advantage to repairing it, is vital for life-support and cannot be turned off, or perhaps it prevents collapse in the vacuum of space. In any case, the term does not make any sense in the context of the movie scene. My best guess is that the writer was just using military, space and aeronautical terms to fill in dialogue and make it sound realistic.

Comment: +1 for a good answer, but the linked post suggests that "feed the leak" is not a deliberate strategy but is rather an unintentional process. (In that paragraph, the user is merely trying "to determine how long the Orbiter can survive at the current leak rate".)

Comment: @MarcInManhattan Correct, I also read this article where it is described as a strategy: https://ntrs.nasa.gov/citations/20140012987 I understand what you're saying - no leak is intentional, but to 'feed' something is always deliberate. Like I said, they could isolate the flow but clearly they cannot do that so they speak in terms of how long they can afford to 'feed' it.

Comment: Hmm, I'm note sure about this statement: *to 'feed' something is always deliberate* I think that the writer was using "feed" in the sense of "That much food would feed my family for a week." (I.e., the item doing the feeding does not do so deliberately but is merely a source of food / fuel to whatever consumes it.)

Comment: @MarcInManhattan Granted, the punctured equipment is just continuing to pump obliviously. But from the moment a human *describes* it in those terms and it becomes a conscious decision to 'feed the leak' instead of isolating it, wouldn't you agree that is a deliberate choice? Even if they have no choice because isolating it would cause loss of life, it's still a 'strategy' in the same sense as any life-saving strategy.

Comment: I wouldn’t be so certain it doesn’t make sense in context: from the transcript it’s not clear if that’s a direct response, because it comes in with a lot of battle chatter. Remembering that Pandora’s atmosphere is toxic to humans, if there’s a leak in the plane then “feeding the leak” by “purging” the cockpit with breathable air is a perfectly understandable response.

Comment: @BenMurphy Depends what you mean by 'context'. If you mean the context of controlling a spacecraft, yes. If you mean the context of a stream of dialogue written to carry a narrative, no.

Comment: The context is: the pilot and Miller are in one ship, Trudy is in another. Trudy fires a volley of bullets through Miller’s windscreen, and he says “Keep her in your sights”. (To the pilot) The pilot says “Purging. Feeding the leak.” (Note that the pilot is much lower in the mix. You can barely hear it.) so in context, it makes perfect sense. The pilot is describing the actions he is taking to keep the ship flying safely, even with a holey windscreen.

Comment: If you want to check it out yourself, I don’t think this is just the extended edition. I just looked at the scene in Disney+, and the relevant dialog is at 2:16:52